# VM acceleration is not working on another VM for Android Emulator

Tags: linux, android-emulator, hardware-acceleration

We want to run our instrumented tests on Gitlab. We've created a Linux runner(amd64,Ubuntu 22.04) to execute connectedAndroidTest gradle task. However we've come across some obstacles.

I have two questions :

- According [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-accel-restrictions), I read that we can not use VM acceleration for android emulator in another VM ? Is it true ?
- Is there anyone able to run the instrumented tests on another VM using VM acceleration? VM acceleration is important because it improves execution speed. Otherwise it will take a long time to start the emulator.

While trying this for android-31(x86_64) emulator, I'm getting error below even if KVM is enabled on VM.

```
KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x8
FATAL   | Emulator: exiting becase of the internal error 'kvm_arch_handle_exit: 
hardware error happened in KVM, aborting now
```

Also I checked these:

```
$./emulator -accel-check
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel

$kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

I thought if the official site says like this, maybe it's true. Otherwise we have to build a physical Linux machine for hardware acceleration or we have to increase our resources on VM and continue without VM acceleration. (cpu,memory etc.) :)

Regards,

Tugce.

Comment: Found but not personally done the following, based on: [Google's Cuttlefish](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/cuttlefish-use) or https://github.com/google/android-emulator-container-scripts it seems that both of them requires that the cloud host provider has `nested virtualization` / KVM access.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. We found a solution by changing Hypervisor. We created a virtual machine on VMware and opened "expose hardware assisted virtualization to the guest os" option. Detailed info: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-2A98801C-68E8-47AF-99ED-00C63E4857F6.html